# How to INSERT into a table that uses sequential GUIDs as a primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, guid

Here is a simplified version of the table I am looking at:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FrustratingTable]
(
    [Id] Uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
    , [SecondField] [datetime]
    , [ThirdField] varchar(128)
)
```

I want to insert new records into this table. I have tried 3 approaches:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FrustratingTable] (Id, SecondField, ThirdField)
    SELECT newid() as Id, 
           '6/25/2015' as SecondField, 'Example' as ThirdField
```

This approach inserts, but the resulting key isn't a nice sequential GUID like the other ones in the table

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FrustratingTable] (Id, SecondField, ThirdField)
SELECT NEWSEQUENTIALID() as Id, '6/25/2015' as SecondField, 'Example' as ThirdField
```

This fails with error

> The newsequentialid() built-in function can only be used in a DEFAULT expression for a column of type 'uniqueidentifier' in a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement. It cannot be combined with other operators to form a complex scalar expression.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FrustratingTable] (SecondField,ThirdField)
SELECT '6/25/2015' as SecondField, 'Example' as ThirdField
```

This fails with the error

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'mydatabase.dbo.frustratingtable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Is it possible to solve this without altering the table definition?

Comment: when you say "resulting key isn't a nice sequential GUID..." can you provide an example?  How were the existing guids created in the table?  Via `newId()`?

Comment: Not using newid(), not created by me. The values in there are all end with the same 20 characters, but the first 16 vary.

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585307/sequential-guids - could the existing table rows have been created via such a method?

Comment: `newsequentialid()` can *only* be used in a `DEFAULT` constraint, as your error message and [the MSDN documentation states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189786.aspx). So **no** - without changing your table structure, you **cannot** fix this

Comment: @Kritner that seems to be the kind of approach I want, but that's talking about a C# function. Is there any way to get a similar behaviour from a SQL statement?

Comment: as marc_s stated, it sounds like you could add a default constraint to that column - though that would be altering the table :/

Comment: also I don't know if they would look like a completely separate sequence from original set in your table or not, I've not had any reason to have sequential guids before... is there a specific reason to use those over a normal guid, or perhaps even an identity column?

Comment: @TheTTGGuy you could *possibly* use one of the C# solutions in the mentioned thread in my above comment, turn it into a CLR function, and reference the function when doing an insert.  This would *not* require a modification to the table... but seems extremely complicated for problem which I'm a little confused as to why it's a problem in the first place (e.g. why do you need sequential guids)

Comment: It's a large dataset. I need the performance.

Comment: What impact does non-sequential GUIDs have on performance?

Comment: Is it actually the PK, the code you show doesn't say it is or isn't, e.g. PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC blah blah) ?

Comment: @PaulZahra OP stated that was attempted in the question body.  It is not a viable solution for OP because it isn't a sequential GUID.

Comment: See http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-302.aspx - DEFAULT constraint only!

Comment: Don't change the network card on the server, if the sequential nature really matters.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You may be able to do this by way of using a table variable:

```
declare @t table (
    ID uniqueidentifier not null default newsequentialid(),
    SecondField datetime,
    ThirdField varchar(128)
)
insert into @t (SecondField,ThirdField)
    output inserted.ID,inserted.SecondField,inserted.ThirdField
    into FrustratingTable
values
('20150101','abc'),
('20150201','def'),
('20150301','ghi')

select * from FrustratingTable
```

Results:

```
Id                                   SecondField             ThirdField
------------------------------------ ----------------------- ------------
1FEBA239-091C-E511-9B2F-78ACC0C2596E 2015-01-01 00:00:00.000 abc
20EBA239-091C-E511-9B2F-78ACC0C2596E 2015-02-01 00:00:00.000 def
21EBA239-091C-E511-9B2F-78ACC0C2596E 2015-03-01 00:00:00.000 ghi
```

Since the table variable sets the value via a `default`, we're allowed to use `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`.

Of course, for very large data sets, there's a penalty in temporarily having two copies of the data lurking around.

---

An alternative would be to use an older solution, called COMBs, which were used before `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` was introduced:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(10)) + CAST(GETDATE() AS BINARY(6)) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

Generates `uniqueidentifiers` with better locality than `NEWID()` by itself does.

Comment: Yes, this is brilliant. in fact, what's to stop me from creating a scalar function that defines a local table variable, inserts one record and returns a GUID, then call this new scalar function when I need a sequential GUID?

Comment: @TheTTGGuy - possibly. I tend to prefer to working with sets so far as possible though. Introducing the scalar function, although reusable, may impose a performance penalty when working with large data sets.

Comment: ok the scalar function failed, but your solution will work within my stored procedure quite well in another way.

Comment: @PhilipDevine - I always love the moment when I go from "nope, it can't be done" to "well, *obviously* you can just do X". This question was one of those.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if first yout take the `[IncrementGuid]` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9116354/659190),
then you can do something like this,

[**Fiddle Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/998cf/7)

```
INSERT [dbo].[FrustratingTable]
SELECT
      [dbo].[IncrementGuid](MAX([Id])),
      '01/01/01',
      '3'
  FROM
      [dbo].[FrustratingTable];
```

### Caveat:

Once you reviewed the function in the other answer, you'll agree, there must be a better way.

Change the code that needs the GUIDs to be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE FrustratingTable
ALTER COLUMN id uniqueidentifier not null default newsequentialid()
```

Comment: You're right, good catch.. that's what I get for being multi platform :)

Comment: I can't alter the table, as I indicated in my question.

Comment: See here for how to add a default constraint. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307075/t-sql-command-for-adding-a-default-constraint

Comment: Ok then you can disregard this answer (and probably most others, because as you can see you need a default constraint to perform what you are looking for, otherwise you need a new solution)