# SQL Server - Generating Sequential Guids for Existing Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure

I need to load data from a legacy SQL Server database which uses numeric primary keys into a new database with a different schema that uses sequential Guids for primary keys. In the new system the sequential Guids are generated by the application - it uses the Azure SQL db which doesn't support `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`.

For performance reasons and as there is a lot of data restructuring I want to convert using SQL scripts (i.e. loading data directly into SQL and not going via the application) and I am planning to add a new Id column to each legacy table for the Ids and populating the Ids in each legacy table before inserting into the new schema

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31073409/how-to-insert-into-a-table-that-uses-sequential-guids-as-a-primary-key) which helpfully provided this SQL to generate unique sequential Ids which I can use to generate my new Ids

```
SELECT 
    CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(10)) + CAST(GETDATE() AS BINARY(6)) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)

UPDATE sometable 
SET Id = CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(10)) + CAST(GETDATE() AS BINARY(6)) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

But I am a confused why the sequential part of the id is at the end of the Guid - wouldn't that cause index fragmentation?

Would it better to change the SQL to this and have the sequential part of the id at the start?

```
CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS BINARY(6)) + CAST(NEWID() AS BINARY(10)) AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
```

Thanks in advance for any insights into which is better

Comment: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alberto_ferrari/archive/2007/08/31/how-are-guids-sorted-by-sql-server.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link -  I never knew that about sorting Guids - so the original version of the SQL to generate sequential Ids is fine